# WordPress - How to get PageSpeed 100/100

Tags: wordpress

I want to increase my PageSpeed score, I tried W3TC but it doesn't help much. Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is too broad, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

W3TC alone is not enough. I highly recommend you to setup CloudFlare, simply because you will benefit from free cdn service that is going to reduce so much bandwidth hit on your website; Resulting into fast page loading.

Also if you are on a dedicated/VPS server you must install Redis on your server and then install redis plugin which is available on wordpress plugins directory.

Here are tutorials that I have used for so many of my clients:

REDIS SETUP FOR WORDPRESS: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-redis-caching-to-speed-up-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04

CLOUDFLARE SETUP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NPSFZI3TTo

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following combination:

wpsupercache
autoptimize
tinypng
cloudflare
changes in htaccess
changes in wpconfig
changes in functions.php

advantage: free and no costs
disadvantages: time effort for optimal settings.